# Magento 2 debugging js ui component in browser

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, debugging

As i am searching debugging of ui component i don't find any great articles to debugging ui component in browser `console` so here i am writing my question.

As we all know magento current system is using knockout js, so i found this link 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/troubleshoot/ui_comp_troubleshoot_js.html but i don't understand how it is work.

As per magento officials doc we can debug data as below link content.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uiregistry.html

But as above link you have to know about your `componentName` for debugging it's data.

But my main concern is if i am currently accessing any custom module or core module form and I want to debug that form data from `console` then how ? because I don't know it's `form` namespace and it's tedious to find form namespace from `element` tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made one solution after working on jquery function calling into console line by line.

As per debugging form data by `uiRegistry` https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uiregistry.html.
We need `componentName`.

So for that I have created jQuery function.

Getting **Grid Component**

```
var gridComponentName = jQuery('div.admin__data-grid-outer-wrap:last').data('bind').split(': ',2)[1].replace(/'/g,'');
```

Getting **Form Component**

```
var formComponentname = jQuery('div.admin__form-loading-mask').data('component');
```

After getting main `componentName` you can pass it into registry

```
var registry = require('uiRegistry');
var component = registry.get(componentName);
console.log(component.namespace);
```

You can debug from this.
Hope this will be helpful!.

Comment: Can i get componentName when js load?

Answer (score 1):

Few steps that i can recommend to debug UI component are:

1. Check your browser console for any js error message.
2. Open your console and open network tab and check your relevant ui
   component call is executing successfully or not. Check if it's
   response contains any error message.
3. Check your **var/log** folder for any error message.
4. If you make any changes to your xml ui component clear the cache and
   check the changes usign the command `bin/magento cache:clean`

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend to **display ALL logs from `layout.js` on your browser `console`**.

To do this, in the file `src/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/core/renderer/layout.js`, add this line after the `'use strict';` line.

```
consoleLogger.setDisplayLevel(consoleLogger.levels.ALL);
```

This would look like:

```
], function (_, $, utils, registry, types, consoleLogger) {
    'use strict';

    consoleLogger.setDisplayLevel(consoleLogger.levels.ALL);

    var templates = registry.create(),
        layout = {},
        cachedConfig = {};
```

This will print on the `console` all steps of initialization for each uiComponents on the page.

Very helpful to know what's going on behind the scene.